Error: expected environment variable `ANCHOR_WALLET` is not set
I had an error, seems like I'm missing something. Hope someone can help

  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  const program = new anchor.Program<Sleep>(IDL);



You might be trying to access anchor-specific variables when not in an anchor workspace. Are you trying to access AnchorProvider  inside your project? also, how are you initializing your program and what version of anchor are you using?

That's all my code in the api, the ultimate goal I want to use my program through idl in the backend

You need to override the default provider.
import { Program, type Provider } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
const myProgram = new Program<ProgramType>(IDL, programID, {} as Provider);


@coral-xyz/anchor v0.29.0 is necessary, the IDL specification was completely rewritten as of v0.30.0

